# Get number of hours worked in Bugzilla using XML-RPC

Tags: bugzilla

I'm using Bugzilla 4.0 and can't seem to find a way to get the number of hours worked on a bug by RPC. It still seems like though Bugzilla saves the information in the comments of a bug but even though `Additional Hours Worked: x` is present when looking inside Bugzilla it is NOT a part of the comment after retrieving it via RPC. I do this with the same user so it shouldn't be a permissions issue. How would I get the hours worked on a bug via RPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be unsupported at this time and I have added a request for it at: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643681